# MSBuild error while building with new build definition

Tags: visual-studio-2012, msbuild

We are working with  VS2008 connected to TFS2012. We have a requirement that if anyone do checkIn changes,then latest version files must be copied to a central folder that is not mapped with TFS. I had done some searching and then i found that if we can do this with build events and all i have to do is create new build definition with triggering at checkin. I can't create build definition in VS2008 so i have created build definition in VS2012 but while building with that it gives error like this

```
Debug | Any CPU
 1 error(s), 3 warning(s)
$/Global Module/cal_reg.sln - 1 error(s), 3 warning(s), View Log File
 C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v3.5\Microsoft.Common.targets (1418): Task failed because "AxImp.exe" was not found, or the correct Microsoft Windows SDK is not installed. The task is looking for "AxImp.exe" in the "bin" subdirectory beneath the location specified in the InstallationFolder value of the registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\WinSDK-NetFx35Tools-x86. You may be able to solve the problem by doing one of the following:  1) Install the Microsoft Windows SDK.  2) Install Visual Studio 2010.  3) Manually set the above registry key to the correct location.  4) Pass the correct location into the "ToolPath" parameter of the task.
 C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v3.5\Microsoft.Common.targets: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "CommonProc". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.
 C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v3.5\Microsoft.Common.targets: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Interop.Word". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.
 C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v3.5\Microsoft.Common.targets: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Interop.Excel". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.
 $/Global Module/cal_reg.sln compiled
 No Test Results
 No Code Coverage Results
Other Errors and Warnings
 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
 Exception Message: MSBuild error 1 has ended this build. You can find more specific information about the cause of this error in above messages. (type BuildProcessTerminateException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at System.Activities.Statements.Throw.Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
   at System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
   at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)
```

I have tried to build in command line using MSBuild.exe but same error occurred.Why this is happening ?what to do?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the answer is in your build logs:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v3.5\Microsoft.Common.targets (1418): Task failed because "AxImp.exe" was not found, or the correct Microsoft Windows SDK is not installed. The task is looking for "AxImp.exe" in the "bin" subdirectory beneath the location specified in the InstallationFolder value of the registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\WinSDK-NetFx35Tools-x86. 
You may be able to solve the problem by doing one of the following:  
1) Install the Microsoft Windows SDK.  
2) Install Visual Studio 2010.  
3) Manually set the above registry key to the correct location.  
4) Pass the correct location into the "ToolPath" parameter of the task.
```

Comment: Microsoft Windows SDK is already installed and path is set to correct location in registry and ToolPath="$(LCToolPath)" set in Microsoft.Common.targets file